When does @RegisterForReflection have to be used?
I am a bit confused with @RegisterForReflection and when does Quarkus actually require it as my application runs perfectly fine in dev or in native mode without it.
In a simple PoC application I have added a quarkus-rest-client-jackson and access the gravatar /profile api.
Client looks like:
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "gravatar")
public interface GravatarClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/v3/profiles/{id}")
    GravatarProfile findById(@PathParam("id") String id);

}

and the model
@Getter
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@ToString
public class GravatarProfile {

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private final String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private final String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("profile_url")
    private final String url;
    @JsonProperty("registration_date")
    private final ZonedDateTime registrationDate;

    @Builder.Default
    @JsonProperty("verified_accounts")
    private final List<Account> verifiedAccounts = List.of();

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @Jacksonized
    @ToString
    public static class Account {

        @JsonProperty("service_type")
        private final String type;

    }

}

In both native and dev mode the deserialization works flawlessly. Based on the documentation I would have expected an exception such like:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.acme.jsonb.Person and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Why is it working? and when should I be careful not forgetting this annotation?

I'm no sure about that but I suppose that GravaterProfile is automatically discovered and registered for reflection by Quarkus; maybe if you return a generic Response and try to unmarshall it's content manually using jackson API you can get the expected exception

Thanks for your reply @LucaBassoRicci I tried using the ObjectMapper and a plain json and returning a Response straight from the controller, with the Client Model or directly using the Domain Model, both got deserialised without an issue.
I was wondering if there was a way to verify which classes have been registered for reflection?
Only thing I see at build time is the following line:
4’024 types,   139 fields, and 3’731 methods registered for reflection

if no one of quarkus post an answer here if a couple of days, file a new discussion in quarkus github and ask there; link this question also.

Quarkus will automatically register a class like yours for reflection if it is part of the method signature of a known integration point. For example, if the class is a return type of JAX-RS / Jakarta REST method, that type will automatically be registered for reflection

Thanks @geoand that helps. Would you know if there is any existing documentation that would explain the magic?

Not explicitly, but you can find some information in https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions
